# typescript multiple type check function

Tags: typescript

### Background

I'm making type checking function with typescript.

```js
const checkType = <T>(value: unknown, isTypeFn: (value: unknown) => value is T): T => {
  if (!isTypeFn(value)) {
    console.error(`${isTypeFn} ${value} does not have correct type`);
    throw new Error(`${value} does not have correct type`);
  }

  return value;
};

const isBoolean = (value: unknown): value is boolean => typeof value === 'boolean';

const isString = (value: unknown): value is string => typeof value === 'string';

const isNumber = (value: unknown): value is number => typeof value === 'number';

const isNull = (value: unknown): value is null => value === null;
```

And I can use it like below.

```js
const a = await getNumber() // this should be number
const numA: number = checkType(a, isNumber); // numA is number or throw Error!
```

### Problem

I want to extend the checkType function like below.

```js
const b = await getNumberOrString();
const bNumOrString: number | string = checkType(b, isNumber, isString);
const bNumOrBoolean: number | boolean = checkType(b, isNumber, isBoolean);
const bStringOrNull: string | null = checkType(b, isString, isNull);
```

How to improve the checkType for it to work like this ?

Comment: `checkType(b, (a) => isNumber(a) || isString((a))`

Comment: Thanks, but I want dynamic type! (I edited my question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `checkType` will need a rest parameter. Let's call it `isTypeFns`. `isTypeFns` is a generic type parameter `T` which will be an array of functions with type predicates.

```
const checkType = <
  T extends ((value: unknown) => value is any)[]
>(value: unknown, ...isTypeFns: T): CheckType<T> => {
  if (isTypeFns.some(fn => fn(value))) {
    console.error(`${value} does not have correct type`);
    throw new Error(`${value} does not have correct type`);
  }

  return value as CheckType<T>;
};
```

The implementation is straight forward. You just need to check if one of the functions in `isTypeFns` returns `true` given the `value`.

The return type gets trickier again. We need to take `T` and *infer* the union of type predicate types.

```
type CheckType<T extends ((value: unknown) => value is any)[]> = 
  T[number] extends ((value: unknown) => value is infer U) 
    ? U 
    : never
```

We use this for the return type of the function. TypeScript does not understand this complex type when it comes to the `return` statement of the implementation. That's why I added an assertion there.

```
const b = "b" as number | string;

const bNumOrString = checkType(b, isNumber, isString);
//    ^? const bNumOrString: string | number

const bNumOrBoolean = checkType(b, isNumber, isBoolean);
//    ^? const bNumOrBoolean: number | boolean

const bStringOrNull = checkType(b, isString, isNull);
//    ^? const bStringOrNull: string | null
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQBYwMYGsAq0YB5NwwAeYMAdgCYDOcAFLQG4CGANgK4wBccbZ6ZAewDuZAJRwAvAD44zdvACWNJmQiiA2gF0ZEuKDhxM6smwC2AIxgAnTYRLlqdRqw7de-YWMky5HOEv8yADNrOABVcX0DOAB+cL0QaLhuMhgGa1BQVAEyKjA4VBQMbFhJOFwogmJSShp6Xy4ePkERcWlZF0VlVQ1NUClneTdmzwAaOAA6KaUSmAAxXO5MUW5kNCwcfB0ZAG8ohSC6GZwFqgmqAVMYWiCybzhbwY5RF7g9xOjs3IEWGAnrKwCKy0AAGABIdg0AL5wCgCGA0QT5JBMdIFIFWND5SCwEGiADcUQMYCQgKEcFS5IAolZAcDwZDOjC4QiKQJkaj4NlaVi4DiYHjCR8oZkPpiwGwrHcGnAmDQ1sVNpgpEKoUKsjk8v4qAAhAQ-GAqMpPRruFpibgygLmfW-I3tfkCQ4yiSuuAAchtBpU7vVIC+WqUAGUwFYFGQAObGhrDDytS2dbVwPJhyP3R3OxOu3TulPhiO+0UB-JKAByZksVmjnVj5pWHXkSZMFlCDpwTobfmzHublcLIFAcogZFQD14qDAChycFMTHDtFE7wMxdlZQADHAAPSbvlIAJUJACNgsChwSwUisZD4r5sAQRSl6rukK61mtCY4zLj4JW53d6bj5wECu5knANJ0gAhKKUQruYZQAETwbKiKAQAPsmob5kKy6avk5jlqYADyVghqmUbPkUGywLQ5iflQBGVnRpH5gSUTbkkAB6MSgCKA4gEAA)

Comment: You were faster :D , upvoted. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WvGY4w) is my example with `assert` function, since OP wants to throw an error